# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Composition requires an active composition context (Android Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, illegalstateexception, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Trying to show an AlertDialog using Jetpack Compose, but App is crashing while calling the AlertDialog function with error as

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Composition requires an active
>   composition context

Please find the code below,

```
@Composable
fun homeScreenCompose() {

    Align(
        alignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Column(
            arrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Spacing(16.dp),
            children = {

                Button(
                    modifier = Height(50.dp) wraps Expanded,
                    text = "Alert Dialog", onClick = {
                        showAlertDialog()
                    }, style = OutlinedButtonStyle(
                        Border(color = Color.Red, width = 1.dp),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(50), //50% percent
                        contentColor = Color.Red,
                        color = Color.White,
                        elevation = Dp(4f)
                    )
                )
            }
        )
    }

}

@Composable
fun showAlertDialog() {
    val openDialog = +state { true }
    if (openDialog.value) {
        AlertDialog(
            onCloseRequest = {
            },
            title = {
                Text(text = "Logout")
            },
            text = {
                Text("Are you sure you have to logout?")
            },
            confirmButton = {
                Button("Yes", onClick = {
                    openDialog.value = false
                })
            },
            dismissButton = {
                Button("No", onClick = {
                    openDialog.value = false
                })
            },
            buttonLayout = AlertDialogButtonLayout.Stacked
        )
    }

}
```

Not able to figure out why it is crashing and what's the solution for this,
any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The trick is that `onClick` is not a composition context, you cannot just show something from there. You have to trigger a refresh through a shared `@Model` or a `+state`.

Comment: You can see a similar example here: https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/5f7f56003fedc50982540450062e3e83b8ddea9f/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/article/ArticleScreen.kt#L65-L69

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Creates a data class for the state model, and it does not have to be marked with the @Model annotation.
2. The initial state itself is created inside the @Composable function using + state.
3. The visibility of the dialog is determined by the visible property of the model obtained by calling the value property.
4. This property can also be set to a new immutable object, as happens in the onClick of both buttons. The first hides itself, the second - closes the dialogue. The dialog can be reopened by clicking on the Ok button, defined inside the same @Composable function.

When trying to make a state outside this function, an error occurs:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Composition requires an active composition context.

The context can be obtained by assigning the value of the `setContent {}` function in `onCreateView`, but how to use it, for example, in Presenter or another class other than `Fragment` or `Activity`, for changing the state is still unclear.

**Check example below**

```
 data class DialogVisibleModel(val visible: Boolean, val dismissPushed: Boolean = false)
    ...
 @Composable
 fun homeScreenCompose() {

   Column {
        SideBySideAlertDialogSample()
   }

 }

@Composable
fun SideBySideAlertDialogSample() {
    val openDialog = +state { DialogVisibleModel(false) }

    Button(text = "Ok", onClick = { openDialog.value = DialogVisibleModel(true) })

    if (openDialog.value.visible) {
        AlertDialog(
            onCloseRequest = {
                // Because we are not setting openDialog.value to false here,
                // the user can close this dialog only via one of the buttons we provide.
            },
            title = {
                Text(text = "Title")
            },
            text = {
                Text("This area typically contains the supportive text" +
                        " which presents the details regarding the Dialog's purpose.")
            },
            confirmButton = {
                Button("Confirm", onClick = {
                    openDialog.value = DialogVisibleModel(false)
                })
            },
            dismissButton = {
                if (!openDialog.value.dismissPushed)
                    Button("Dismiss", onClick = {
                        openDialog.value = DialogVisibleModel(true, true)
                    })
                else {
                    //hidden
                }
            },
            buttonLayout = AlertDialogButtonLayout.SideBySide
        )
    }
}
```